# Merging a remote .gitattribute file with local .gitattribute file with merging strategy union

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-p4

I am working with git p4 rebase and git LFS. unfortunately after syncing the P4 contents to local git repo, it removes all the existing LFS tracked files from .gitattributes, and adds files to .gitattributes that were synced.

example:

Local and remote .gitattributes file before sync

```
    File 1 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 2 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

local .gitattributes file after sync

```
    File 4 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 5 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Now, if I push to remote, I will lose tracking on 1,2,3. So before I push I need to merge the remote .gitattributes file with the local .gitattributes file to obtain

```
    File 1 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 2 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 4 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
    File 5 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Then I can push to remote.

Comment: Your statement seems to be correct: using union merge on `.gitattributes` should get you the right result. Given that you can specify union merge for a file in `.gitattributes`, you should be able to modify `.gitattributes` to request a union merge. What, then, is your question?

Comment: I have tried putting the following into .gitattributes, ".gitattributes merge=union" It did not work

Comment: I'm not an expert on p4, but how come the conflict was not signaled? Aren't you using any Xtheirs option

Comment: It may be difficult to do but if you can construct a [mcve], that would enable others to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works

`git show origin/master:.gitattributes > ./.gitattributes.theirs
touch blankFile
git merge-file --union .gitattributes blankFile .gitattributes.theirs`

if you do not want to overrride .gitattributes you can do

`git merge-file -p --union .gitattributes blankFile .gitattributes.theirs > .gitattributes.new`